# Conda Activate batch file

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, anaconda, syntax-error

I am trying to install anaconda alongside python, without having anaconda on path. I created a batch script that worked yesterday but not today for some reason.

```
@echo off 
C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
```

I named it conda-activate and when I entered conda activate it opened the base environment. Now it doesn't.

Here is a script that works for powershell:

```powershell
& 'C:\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:\Anaconda3'
```

Expand snippet

And this is the contents of conda-hook.ps1

```powershell
$Env:CONDA_EXE = "C:/Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe"
$Env:_CE_M = ""
$Env:_CE_CONDA = ""
$Env:_CONDA_ROOT = "C:/Anaconda3"
$Env:_CONDA_EXE = "C:/Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe"
$CondaModuleArgs = @{ChangePs1 = $True}
Import-Module "$Env:_CONDA_ROOT\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1" -ArgumentList $CondaModuleArgs

Remove-Variable CondaModuleArgs
```

Comment: python doesn't run .exe files. It runs .py files

Comment: @PaulH whoops! not sure how that got there. Whatever I had yesterday worked, I should have taken notes. Any idea how to open conda environment in a terminal with a bat file??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really not sure if this is related or not because I don't have much of backround knowledge. you tell me...

I wrote a batch file starting jupyter notebook for me.
I googled around back then and came out with this:

```
cd /d "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\"
call C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir="C:\Python"
```

So when trying to activate your conda environment, your need to change directory with `cd` and call the `activate.bat` file

Comment: I want it to open the environment in the current terminal, I have it for powershell just not cmd

Comment: ok, it was worth a shot. I guess you should add that information into your question. I'll delete this answer again soon

Comment: No don't delete it

Comment: actually, this worked, well part of it. Good thing you didn't delete it! Thanks for the help